# Open QLPreviewPanel in 'multi display' mode

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, quicklook, qlpreviewcontroller

I'm using QLPreviewPanel to display the contents of a folder. By default this shows the first item and then the user can tap the multi display button to display them all. I would like to go into multi display by default but I can't see a way to do that.

This is for an internal application so private API calls are acceptable.

The images below demonstrate the two modes. It opens as in the first image but I'd like it to open as the second.

[image: Clicking the multi select button]

[image: Opens this]